# Bridge cast required, inconsistent warning while trying to use CGPathRef

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I was just configuring an `CABasicAnimation` for shadowPath property and this made me curious:

```
shadowAnimation.toValue = (id)newShadowPath.CGPath;
```

*[note: shadowAnimation is an `CABasicAnimation` object and `newShadowPath` is an `UIBezierPath` object]*

this works and no error/warning is visible in Xcode. However if I write that like so:

```
CGPathRef test = newShadowPath.CGPath;
shadowAnimation.toValue = (id)test;
```

This won't compile, throwing this warning message:

```
Cast of C pointer type 'CGPathRef' (aka 'const struct CGPath *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast
```

So it requires me to type it like:

```
shadowAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)test;
```

Now why is this so? Why don't I get the same error in the initial example when I use only **(id)newShadowPath.CGPath**; ? Would it be correct to place `__bridge` cast there too regardless of Xcode not detecting any problems? Or am I missing what's the difference here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the difference lies in the new (and a bit complicated) conversion rules introduced in clang 3.1.

First, lets boil it down:

```
@@interface Foo : NSObject
+ (CGPathRef)bar;
@end

CGPathRef foo();

void test()
{
    // works without bridged cast:
    id a = (id)[Foo bar];

    // needs bridged cast
    id b = (__bridge id)foo();
}
```

So when casting the result of a message we can omit the brdge cast while a normal function call needs it. That seems strange.

The reason for the difference lies in how ARC interprets functions and method names and derives assumptions about the retain count of so called [C retainable pointer types](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#arc-misc-c-retainable) (Core Foundation objects).

In [section 3.3.2](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#conversion-to-retainable-object-pointer-type-of-expressions-with-known-semantics) of the ARC guide ("Conversion to retainable object pointer type of expressions with known semantics") you'll find the reason for the discrepancy:

> An expression is **known unretained** if it is an rvalue of C
>   retainable pointer type and it is [...] a message send [...]

and

> If the cast operand is **known unretained** [...] the
>   conversion is treated as a __bridge cast

The same section describes why this not applies to C functions and how they can be decorated to enable clang to make similar assumptions. So we can modify the example from above to get rid of the bridge cast for the C function call, as well:

```
CGPathRef foo() __attribute__((cf_returns_not_retained));
```

To answer your final question: It's safe to use the bridge cast in both places. It even makes sure ARC picks the right `__bridge` cast (it could pick the `__bridge_transfer` cast depending on the name of the method. In this case it would use `__bridge`, though).

Comment: wow, thanks for going into such effort to analyze this. I re-accepted this as the correct answer because it goes into this great length to exactly explain whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by ARC, and the magic that it does when assignments occur.

When you create a temporary variable `CGPathRef test` and assign to it, ARC sees that you're using a CoreBlank instance that doesn't follow the standard memory paradigms and doesn't retain it or do anything fancy.

Later, when you attempt to assign this non-managed instance to a retained `id`-typed property, LLVM freaks right out, because it thought it didn't have to manage the memory for that instance, but now it should start to (which is the intent of the `__bridge` keyword).

In the first code snippet, the reason it works is because ARC always knows that it should treat that instance as ARC-managed and there never exists a reference to it which isn't ARC managed.

Comment: I don't see how this explanation makes anything clearer. Why does `id a = (id)[UIBezierPath new];` work, yet `id b = (__bridge id)CGPathCreateCopy(NULL);` needs the bridge cast?

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe `UIBezierPath` is an ARC-managed class, in that it's not a C-pointer, it's an Objective-C pointer. `CGPathCreateCopy` returns a C struct pointer, which ARC does not manage unless bridged.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I meant `id a = (id)[UIBezierPath new].CGPath;`. So the difference between the two cases is only that `a` gets the result of an objc message while `b` gets the result of a C function. I don't see why ARC should handle these cases differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand now! Is the term CoreBlank your invention? :) I never heard of it.